# onVisitHighlightedLine cannot push classname using Rehype Pretty code

Tags: next.js, mdxjs, rehypejs, contentlayer

I'm using [Rehype Pretty code](https://rehype-pretty-code.netlify.app/) to add syntax highlighting to my MDX blog. But I'm not able to get the line highlighting to work.

As per the documentation and few [other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73003034/6908282), below is the configuration that should work, but I'm getting the following error.

> _mdx_bundler_entry_point-f0976fc3-b34d-45fd-a559-565325298b22.mdx:0:0: ERROR: [plugin: @mdx-js/esbuild] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') at onVisitHighlightedLine

```js
const options = {
    theme: 'one-dark-pro', // 'github-dark-dimmed' is default

    onVisitLine(node) {
        // Prevent lines from collapsing in `display: grid` mode, and allow empty
        if (node.children.length === 0) {
            node.children = [{ type: "text", value: " " }]
        }
    },
    onVisitHighlightedLine(node) {
        node.properties.className.push("line--highlighted");
    },
    onVisitHighlightedWord(node) {
        node.properties.className = ["word--highlighted"]
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading through the log and debugging the node, it shows that the `className` is `undefined` and hence its not an array - so I cannot use `Array.push` method. So I modified the code to check if className is an array:

```js
const options = {
    theme: 'one-dark-pro', // 'github-dark-dimmed' is default

    onVisitLine(node) {
        if (node.children.length === 0) {
            // if code block has a empty line, add a space instead of keeping it blank
            node.children = [{ type: "text", value: " " }]
        }
    },
    onVisitHighlightedLine(node) {
        const nodeClass = node.properties.className;
        console.log("Highlighted Line", {node})
        if (nodeClass && nodeClass.length > 0) {
            node.properties.className.push("line--highlighted");
        }else{
            node.properties.className = ["line--highlighted"];
        }
    },
    onVisitHighlightedWord(node) {
        node.properties.className = ["word--highlighted"]
    },
};
```